# searching for multiple keys with swift 4

Tags: ios, firebase, search, swift4

i have a simple app that allows people to post a post and now i have made a search bar so that people can search for the posts but i want to allow the user to either search for the `title` of a post or the `location` of a post or search for the title of the post and the location at the same time. my search is searching through my firebase database but i can only assign it to search for either `title` or `location`. i have a little problem to make it so it searches for the boths keys at the same time

my code to filter and search looks like this

```
 func filterContent(searchText:String) {
    self.filteredUsers = self.userArray.filter{user in

    //  let title = user!["title"] as? String
        let adress = user!["adress"] as? String

    // return(title?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
        return(adress?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!


    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

obviously you can see that i can only return 1 of the searches do you know any way i can return both of these?

i have also tried this

```
 func filterContent(searchText:String) {
    self.filteredUsers = self.userArray.filter{user in

      let title = user!["title"] as? String
      let adress = user!["adress"] as? String


     return(adress?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))! &&  (title?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!


    }

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

but code only allows the search function to function if for example both the title and the address is named "apple" then it will work but if `title` is named "apple" and `adress` is named "orange" and i would search for either "apple" or "orange" nothing would show up since the `&&` work as a bool and is only working  if the key of the `title` and the `location` is the same. therefore i am still at square one and wonder how i could possibly get the search filter to search through both `title` and `address`

Answer (score 1):

```
func filterContent(searchText:String) {
 self.filteredUsers = self.userArray.flatMap { (temp) -> User in
   return temp
   }.filter { (aUser) -> Bool in
     return aUser.address?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) == true || aUser.title?.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) == true
  }
  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

or, a little closer put below..

```
func filterContent(searchText:String) {
  self.filteredUsers = self.userArray.filter{ user in
    let title = user!["title"] as? String
    let address = user!["adress"] as? String
    return title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) == true || address.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) == true
  }
  tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I think the big things are that you'll want flatmap to remove nil users, then I like localizedCaseInsensitiveContains() on top of a string directly. hope this helps.

I declared user as a struct inside playgrounds to make sure this works well. The best way to do this operation fast may be creating a realm user then filtering results using a predicate. (performance)